# Will Tor block favicons by default?

Tags: anonymity, website

I realized this was possible years ago but people told me I was crazy and that it was impossible.

https://www.ghacks.net/2021/01/22/favicons-may-be-used-to-track-users/

Answer (score 1):

No, Tor Browser does not block favicons.

From the paper:

> Nonetheless, browsers like Brave have recently adopted built-in anti-fingerprinting techniques which can affect our attack's performance (while Tor has done so for years, we do not consider it in our experiments since it is not susceptible to our favicon attack).

So this is not an issue for Tor Browser.

> As  part  of  our  experiments  we  also  test  Firefox. [...] In fact, while monitoring the browser during the  attack’s  execution  we  observe  that  it  has  a  valid  favicon cache which creates appropriate entries for every visited page with  the  corresponding  favicons.  However,  it never actually uses the cache to fetch the entries. As a result, Firefox actually issues requests to re-fetch favicons that are already present in the  cache.  We  have  reported  this  bug  to  the  Mozilla  team, who verified and acknowledged it. [...] Nonetheless, we believe that once this  bug  is  fixed  our  attack  will  work  in  Firefox,  unless they also deploy countermeasures to mitigate our attack [...].

It's also not an issue in the current Firefox.